# AutoPostBack not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, postback, rad-controls

I am having trouble with using AutoPostBack on a RadGrid, a dropdown list, and a button. I have it set to Auto post back whenever the data column is filtered/sorted on the RadGrid, whenever the ddl is changed, and whenever the button is pressed. I unfortunately cannot get it to work. I have the  AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" set for each column that I want to post back. And I have AutoPostBack="true" on both the ddl and button.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />

<GraphBtn:WinampButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" TemplateName="GoNext" Text="Go" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

But instead of 'refreshing' the page, what happens is it just sorts the current column or changes the information. How come its not 'firing' the post-back like it has done before? Instead it seems like its loading by AJAX but I don't have AJAX on my page at all.

The behind VB does change the values by SQL. Before it used to have no problem firing the postback and now I cannot get it to work. I unfortunately need it to use the post-back for the RadGrid to function correctly.

Note: It is not in an update panel either.

Comment: Can you please add ajaxification by ajax manager code?

Comment: The ajax manager worked. Thanks!

Comment: If I add the answer could you mark it? ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a RadAjaxManager to your page:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="masterAjaxManager" runat="server" />
```

After this you can bind the related controls in code behind:

```
masterAjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(ajaxifiedControl, updatedControl)
```